# Find the volume of space between cylinders

Tags: geometry, circles, volume

volume between cylinders

[image]

How would I find the between the gaps in the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In top view the area of one gap is equal to the difference of a circle and it's circumscribed square. So,

$A_{gap} = d^2 - \pi \frac{d^2}{4} = \frac{25}{4} (4- \pi)$

Multiplying by height and total gaps gives the result

$A_{total} = 36 × A_{gap} = 225 (4 - \pi )$